# Order by numbers with bash wildcards

Tags: bash, shell, wildcard

I have a directory that contains

frame0.png
frame1.png
frame2.png
...
frame20.png

I want to use wildcards such that ls -l shows me the files ordered by the number. I tried

```
ls -l frame?.png frame??.png
```

because I thought it would first seach for the items with just one digit, order them and then do the same with two digits but, the output is

frame0.png
frame10.png
frame11.png
...
frame1.png
frame20.png
frame2.png
...
frame9.png

How can I circumvent that bash orders them like that?

Comment: look at some of the 21 Q/A s found for [bash zero pad filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbash%5D+zero+pad+filenames) . Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have gnu utilities then use `-v` option to get natural sort:

```
ls -lv frame*.png
```

If you don't have gnu `ls` then try this `find + sort`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'frame*.png' | sort -V
```